# Как вызвать цифровую клавиатуру в андроиде?

Tags: android

Сразу говорю, InpuType="date" мне не подходит, т.к. хочу вводить дату в формате "дд.мм.гггг", а в стандартном вводится через / и не дает вставить ничего лишнего.
У меня подключен TextWatcher, который подставляет точки в нужных местах, не хватает только цифровой клавиатуры(

Comment: формат дд.мм.гггг плох. Если приложение попадет в Америку, то там будет вводить в ступор. Так как там как раз через точку и пишут, но только месяц впереди.

Настойчиво рекомендую не выдумывать и использовать общепринятые стандарты. А менеджеров, которые такое выдумывают, бить по голове.

Comment: Да, менеджеры это тяжко(
Меня уверили, что на зарубежную аудиторию мы пока не рассчитываем.
В итоге я справилась inputType=phone, повесила фильтр и TextWatcher

Answer (score 2):

Думаю подойдет

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

Comment: Не помогает, перестает работать TextWatcher и не подставляется автоматически точка.

Answer (score 1):

Соглашусь с [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) что надо использовать стандартные. По идее если указаны региональные настройки, то при вводе должен "подхватывать" правильный разделитель даты.

Если все равно не устраивает, то можно кастомизировать ввод через [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) - `EditText.setFilters()`

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть поле для ввода, в котором нужны только цифры, и так же использую TextWatcher для подстановки пробелов между группами цифр. Добавил в EditText

```
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

При выборе поля выводится только цифровая клавиатура. И пробелы нормально пускает